# typescript: how to set computed property as keyof...?

Tags: typescript

i can't figure out why this code doesn't compile with TypeScript@2.6.2

```
class TestClass<T extends object, K extends keyof T>
{
    [key:K]:T[K];

    constructor(value:T)
    {
        Object.assign(this, value);
    }
}
```

this the error message for `[key:K]:T[K]`;

***Error:(3, 6) TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.***

someone can help?

i get the same error also with:

```
class Options<T extends object>
{
    [K in keyof T]:T[K];

    constructor(value:T)
    {
        Object.assign(this, value);
    }
}
```

but i get these errors:

```
Error:(3, 5) TS2464: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
Error:(3, 6) TS2304: Cannot find name 'K'.
Error:(3, 11) TS2304: Cannot find name 'keyof'.
Error:(3, 17) TS2663: Cannot find name 'T'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.T'?
Error:(3, 22) TS2304: Cannot find name 'K'.
Error:(3, 17) TS1005: ']' expected.
Error:(3, 18) TS1005: ';' expected.
Error:(3, 19) TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
Error:(3, 21) TS1005: '=' expected.
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do?  That code looks like maybe you want `TestClass` to extend a generic `T`, or maybe you want it to hold just one property in common with `T`.  How are you intending to use this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapped types can't be used in classes or interfaces, they can only be used in type aliases (`type=`). Although the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114) for this feature does mention this explicitly all examples use only type aliases.

A work around would be to define a type alias, and create a function that build the object:

```
type Options<T extends object> = 
{
    [K in keyof T]:T[K];
}

function Options<T  extends object >(value:T) : Options<T>
{
    return Object.assign({}, value);
}

var c = Options({ t: 0});
```