# Is it possible to auto generate class properties from its generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there any way in TypeScript to generate class with properties from its generic type like the following:

```js
class SomeClass<T> {
  // Read props from T somehow here?
}

interface Props {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
}

const obj = new SomeClass<Props>;

// So now both obj.a and obj.b are available in autocomplete with correct types from Props interface

interface Props2 {
  some: string;
  other: number;
  props: boolean;
}

const obj2 = new SomeClass<Props2>;
// Now only three props from Props2 are available to obj2
```

I don't want to add something like

```js
class SomeClass {
  [prop: string]: any
}
```

because it will only allow any property to be assigned there and I want to have fixed list from generic type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for here is something closer to a [mixin](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743) than standard inheritance.  But *generic* mixins of the `interface X<T> extends T` variety [are not supported by TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743#issuecomment-414548738).

You can make an object named `SomeClass` and a generic type named `SomeClass<T>` that, with some type assertions, is usable this way, but you do run into some limitations.  Here's how I might do it:

```
class _SomeClass<T> {
    constructor(t: T) {
        Object.assign(this, t);
    }
    // inside here we don't know about properties of T, though
    // so you'll have to do assertions
    get<K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K] {
        return (this as any as T)[k]; // assertion
    }
}
type SomeClass<T> = T & _SomeClass<T>;
const SomeClass = _SomeClass as new <T>(t: T) => SomeClass<T>;
```

The class `_SomeClass<T>` is generic but is not known to itself implement `T`.  The constructor assigns the properties in a `T` object to `this` (you need something like this assignment to get a valid `T` at runtime).  Inside the `_SomeClass<T>` implementation you need assertions whenever you try to access any properties of `T` on `this` (so `this as any as T` or `this as this & T` are your friends).

Then the type `SomeClass<T>` is defined as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of `_SomeClass<T>` and `T`, and then the value `SomeClass` is just the `_SomeClass` constructor but we assert that it acts like a `SomeClass<T>` constructor.

Let's see that it works:

```
interface Props {
    a: number;
    b: boolean;
}

const obj = new SomeClass<Props>({ a: 1, b: true });
console.log(obj.a); // 1
console.log(obj.get("a")); // 1

interface Props2 {
    some: string;
    other: number;
    props: boolean;
}

const obj2 = new SomeClass<Props2>({ some: "", other: 2, props: false });
```

Those compile with the IntelliSense you expect.

There are still limitations, of course.  TypeScript really only allows you to `extends` classes where the key names are known statically.  So if you need a generic *subclass* of `SomeClass`, you're out of luck:

```
class Nope<T> extends SomeClass<T> { // error!
/* Base constructor return type 'SomeClass<T>' is 
 not an object type or intersection of object types 
 with statically known members. */
}
```

A *concrete* subclass will work (as long as `keyof T` is known statically):

```
class Okay extends SomeClass<Props> {

}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAED6DKB7AtgUwMLigHgCoD5oBvAKGnOmEQDsIAXAJwFdg7EGAKOgLmlwEpiZCiIDyAIwBWqVgDpIEAJYBzalwAWiiABpodfgG5h5AL7HoAegvRFtRQBNU0dagZOA7k-s0A5HWgA1tSI7tBg4ohM-gAODIjRrnSKqDCIAGZ8unTqkcrq5lbQEIjQAJ6RPiAgzmAAbk5s0N5hUImKNBDmyqh02ADS0KgAHnSo1PYwAajlGQQcAbx9-Ly4ANp9ALpCIiJudEwM1NAaWi16mjAAZHz8qwEbBpbWCm005mZmdKUJ0EhomAo8IQALx8aDXBAoDBYCBAoxUWj+P7QhTQUGQ-4ws7UVChIFcFaCYGEZEAnAEIwkWyjBhpMDAJwABTi0RgpBEYF41CYyHEriMInEvAiiBAqDA1CMZhICPo0EQUjR0BxoVJMOwzPiEHwHCIYV4AEZdEK9MwnCZDDKOqLULIQIhlBwFZJ5IYntADVbaDa7Q6nVJZN06BwAERgEP8N2FT1U6g0ukM6Ca1kAJm2FGKaF49AYtmUAooiGyri5PL5DAL5FiWuFiBtEqlJC9cudadBKt+ULJsOTEBTOr1mdQvBDId0RZcDF4Kd01dZvDpIAg5stTdAqIAcvFUEDBiMxhNO5jAQRiO7XHEGABCEgWABU0AAQpAnLLGCw2AxoHsDkcvj8fDVE98B8GwYDIYJ-AleUpBkfx-ycdgbDjVxl1YdojnSGDpFYPRvhSaAyHcRRsiKOgwCSYAwCqUpAmCdwjjQXlUNkaA7wsEgzHXKBoFEAIwFo4ZRnGGAgJwXtCFITigA)

Answer (score 0):

Mapped types cannot be used in classes.  But, building off the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48345383/626911, you could create a function to create an object with the properties defined matching an interface like this:

```
interface Props {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
}

function build<T>(value?: T): T {
  return Object.assign({}, value);
}


const obj = build<Props>();
// obj contains typed a and b properties

// Or, pass in default values
// const obj = build<Props>({ a: 2, b: false });
```

Comment: What if Props extend other interface and the final interface has some object members?