# Best way to get dynamic type definition in typescript from a configuration object

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have a system in normal javascript where a model can be defined with types as a method override and are casted when the data comes in, but want to get the typescript benefits purely on the assignment (not the instantiation, or at least not as important).

the typescript should be a product of a configuration dictionary / plain object. is there a way to define the following pattern dynamically? I did see some examples of defining a dict but i want to do it for any model not specifically one (which would still require the code duplication)

i saw maybe can make a typescript plugin or do interface code generation. after looking around i didnt see any similar answers that did this. just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on best way to accomplish or if its just not possible.

**Dynamically produce the typings from attributes?**

User uses model . model is our base model class that used public attributes with types to cast and set things like readonly or any. need to add typescript but basically repeats myself from what should be easily derived from the source of truth `definePublicAttributes`

```
export class User extends Model {
  // can i automate the process of generating this below from
  // definePublicAttributes
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  email?: string;
  state?: string;
  countryCode?: string;
  lookupCreditBalance?: number;
  creditTime?: Date;

  // this will pull in andd assign to the instance when data dict
  // is passed..can this be read or provided some way 
  definePublicAttributes(any) {
    return {
      first_name: String,
      last_name: String,
      email: String,
      state: String,
      country_code: String,
      lookup_credit_balance: Number,
      create_time: Date,
      is_anonymous: any.readOnly,
      profile_url: any.readOnly,
    }
  }
```

for a complete minimum reproducable example see a contrived simplified version of what im doing

*(p.s. please note outside of initial cast the model system is used throughout the lifecycle of the app for other things like changes but ommitted for simplicity)*

**Minimum reproducable example**

Two models (`Pet` and `Person`) extends base `Model`, instantiated from a nested plain object and model type definitions. i just want typescript to prevent bad type assignments and docs while editing, but without maybe needing to explictly write the type definitions, instead, getting it from a property / method / source like the `get publicAttributes()`.

```
class Model {
  get publicAttributes() {
    return {}
  }
  
  cast(value, type=null) {
    if (type === Date) {
      return new Date(value);
    } else if (type === Number) {
      return Number(value);
    } else if (type === String) {
      return value.toString();
    } else if (Model.isModel(type)) {
        const model = new type(value);
        return model;
    } else if (Array.isArray(type)) {
        return value.map((item) => {
          return this.cast(item, type[0]);
        });
    } else if (typeof type === 'function') {
      // if function, invoke and pass in
      return this.cast(value, type(value))
    }
    return value;
  }
  
  static isModel(val) {
    return (
      val?.prototype instanceof Model ||
      val?.constructor?.prototype instanceof Model
    );
  }
  
  constructor(data={}) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      this[key] = this.cast(value, this.publicAttributes[key] || null);
    }
  }
}

class Pet extends Model {
  // can below be progammatically derived (?)
  name?: string
  type?: string
  
  get publicAttributes() {
   return {
      name: String,
      type: String,
    }
  }
}

class Person extends Model {
   // can below be progammatically derived (?)
  joined?: Date
  name?: string
  age?: number
  skills?: Array<string>
  locale?: any
  pets?: Array<Pet>
  
  get publicAttributes() {
    return {
      joined: Date, // primative
      name: String, // primative
      age: Number, // primative
      skills: [String], // primative arr
      locale: (v) => v === 'vacation' ? null : String, // derived type via fn
      pets: [Pet], // model arr   
    }
  }
}


const bill = new Person({
   joined: '2021-02-10',
   name: 'bill',
   age: '26',
   skills: ['python', 'dogwalking', 500],
   locale: 'vacation',
   pets: [
      {
        name: 'rufus',
        type: 'dog',
      },
   ]
});

console.log(bill);
```

Comment: Might not be what you want but you can use `<T>` [is-it-possible-to-auto-generate-class-properties-from-its-generic-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58544067/is-it-possible-to-auto-generate-class-properties-from-its-generic-type) and `T` will be `definePublicAttributes` as interface :-?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code here to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now there are a lot of errors unrelated to your question (missing types and values, and the type `Number` is suspect). If you make it easier for others to work on it then it will be easier for them to make useful and testable suggestions. If you do decide to edit to provide a [mre] and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz i provided a simplified version of my actual implementation, if you want to take a look.  i guess Number is also used in typescript but changed it to lowercase number in the original code snippet. right now there is no typescript in the main implementation so ignore the function signatures for now if there are any missing typings in the base model class / etc outside of the class property typescript typings.

Comment: Using [decorators with `emitDecoratorMetadata`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata), you could generate the `definePublicAttributes` from the type annotations

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK9ZoN) meet your needs? If so I could write up my answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Note that in order for your code to be a [mre] I had to add lots of `any` annotations in `Model` to suppress distracting errors I think are not related to your question.  If I'm right about that, could you add those same annotations to `Model` in the question? If I'm wrong, what specifically did I get wrong?  oh and pls mention @jcalz again to ping me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz ! nice thanks! i think one thing is the function would maybe act as a factory and just be any for the definition (the function return value would be the return type which maybe should just be an any!. 

while it does work, im not sure i understand the ins and outs of ModelFromAttributes imnplementation, if you can explain it ! but appreciate it. the annotations you have or correct btw yes

Comment: "i think one thing is the function would maybe act as a factory and just be any for the definition (the function return value would be the return type which maybe should just be an any!." I don't understand this; could you please clarify?  *Which* function should return `any` and why?

Comment: @jcalz A real pity that [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ70Zw) doesn't work

Comment: @Bergi mm yeah much more readable. 

@jcalz re func, in ref to `locale: (v: any) => v === 'vacation' ? null : String` was in reference  to how i use it as almost a type factory based on conditions passed in. i understand this probably is the hardest to dynamically type so any maybe would suffice. an example i use is`filters: [FilterFactory]` where `FilterFactory = (filterData) => filterData.type === 'multi' ? MultiTypeFilter : SingleTypeFilter` thus the typescript equiveland woudl be either `Array<Filter>` (base class)  or `Array<MultiTypeFilter or SingleTypeFilter>`

Comment: Okay maybe I understand what you're talking about; you want the output of the function to determine the type.  Does something like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mxaO8W) work better? If so I'll write it up; if not, what am I still missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz again btw, and you have to only @ one person in a comment; I didn't get your previous one because you mentioned Bergi first.  If I don't get an inbox notification then it's pretty easy for me to lose track of these questions)

Comment: @jcalz Just follow them all to catch them all :-)

Comment: @jcalz this works! amazing, perhaps you can explain in your write up what exactly is happening in various areas ex.  publicAttributes: T
    } & Model & Partial<_MFA<T>>;` or maybe im too green on typescript at the moment ;p

Comment: Okay I will write up a full answer explaining when I get a chance.

Comment: jcalz (no mention): no, I mean the follow button, which should lead to notifications for you for every new comment on the question

Comment: Hmm I thought I had tried that and it didn’t consistently work but I will try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can envision this working is if you write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *class factory function* (let's call it `ModelFromAttributes()`) that takes the `publicAttributes` value as its input of generic type `T` and produces an appropriate subclass of `Model` as its output, whose type is a determined by `T`.  The relationship between `T` (the type of `publicAttributes`) and the output class's instance type is somewhat complex, so we will need to define a helper type (let's also call it `type ModelFromAttributes<T>`) to capture that.

So we will need something like:

```
declare function ModelFromAttributes<T extends object>(
    atts: T): new (args?: any) => ModelFromAttributes<T>;

type ModelFromAttributes<T extends object> = /* impl here */;
```

And we will use it like

```
class Pet extends ModelFromAttributes(
    {
        name: String,
        type: String
    }
) { }


class Person extends ModelFromAttributes({
    joined: Date, 
    name: String, 
    age: Number, 
    skills: [String], 
    locale: (v: any) => v === 'vacation' ? null : String, 
    pets: [Pet],
}) { }
```

---

So `ModelFromAttributes({...})` takes an input of type `T` and produces an output with a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) whose instance type is `ModelFromAttributes<T>`.  So what type is that?

Well, we want a `ModelFromAttributes<T>` to have a `publicAttributes` property of type `T`, and it should also be a `Model` since it will inherit from `Model`, and it should also have a bunch of [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose names and types are determined by `T` in some way.  So it should look like:

```
type ModelFromAttributes<T extends object> =
    { publicAttributes: T } & Model & Partial<MFA<T>>;
```

where we are using [the `Partial<X>` helper type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to turn all the properties into optional ones, and where `MFA<T>` is an as-yet undefined type that needs to represent the conversion of the type `T` of the attributes to the type `MFA<T>` of the corresponding class properties.  The [intersection operator (`&`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) can be read as "and"; a `ModelFromAttributes<T>` is an object with a `publicAttributes` property of type `T`, *and* it is a `Model`, *and* it is an all-optional version of `MFA<T>`, whatever that is.

---

Okay, now we have to define `MFA<T>`. Here's one possible definition:

```
type MFA<T> =
    T extends typeof Date ? Date :
    T extends typeof String ? string :
    T extends typeof Number ? number :
    T extends typeof Boolean ? boolean :
    T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R :
    T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? MFA<R> :
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: MFA<T[K]> } :
    T;
```

This is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks `T` and evaluates to different things based on the check.

So, if `T` is assignable to `typeof Date` (using the [type-level `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to describe the type of the value named `Date`), then `MFA<T>` should be `Date`.  If `T` is the type of the `String` constructor, then `MFA<T>` should be `string`.  And the same for number and boolean.

If `T` is some other class constructor type, then `MFA<T>` should be the instance type of that class (using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract that class type).

If `T` is some other function type, then `MFA<T>` should start with the return type of that function, but because the return type might itself be something like the `String` or `Date` constructor, we need to apply `MFA<>` to that type recursively.  That is, `MFA<T>` is a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).

Finally, if `T` is some other object type, then `MFA<T>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), for each property in `T` with key `K`, we take the property value type `T[K]` and apply `MFA<>` to it itself.  So this is another recursive step.  Also note that [mapped types on arrays/tuples produce arrays/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) so it should automatically work as desired on arrays without extra work.

---

Before moving on, let's make sure it acts as expected on your `Pet` and `Person` attribute types:

```
const petAttributes = {
    name: String,
    type: String
};
type PetModelProps = MFA<typeof petAttributes>
/* type PetModelProps = {
    name: string;
    type: string;
} */
```

That looks good so far.  We don't have a `Pet` class constructor yet so let's just describe one with a hand-crafted interface that should be the same thing:

```
interface PetModel extends Partial<PetModelProps>, Model {
    publicAttributes: PetModelProps
}
const personAttributes = {
    joined: Date,
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    skills: [String],
    locale: (v: any) => v === 'vacation' ? null : String,
    pets: [null! as new () => PetModel], // just for typing purposes
}

type PersonModelProps = MFA<typeof personAttributes>
/* type PersonModelProps = {
    joined: Date;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    skills: string[];
    locale: string | null;
    pets: PetModel[];
} */
```

Also looks good.

---

Okay, all we have left to do is actually implement `ModelFromAttributes()`.  Like this:

```
function ModelFromAttributes<T extends object>(atts: T) {
    return class extends Model {
        get publicAttributes() { return atts }
    } as any as new (args?: any) => ModelFromAttributes<T>;
}
```

I used [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in there to suppress compiler errors.  The compiler has no good way to understand that the class expression actually constructs instances of `ModelFromAttributes<T>`; a generic conditional type like `ModelFromAttributes<T>` where `T` is not specified yet is essentially opaque to the compiler.  Generally speaking the compiler won't be able to look at a class declaration or expression and infer dynamic property keys; classes generate interface types, and interfaces can only have statically known property names.  So something like a type assertion will be necessary.

All that means is we need to be careful that our implementation does what we say it does.

---

So let's try it:

```
class Pet extends ModelFromAttributes(
    {
        name: String,
        type: String
    }
) { }

class Person extends ModelFromAttributes({
    joined: Date,
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    skills: [String],
    locale: (v: any) => v === 'vacation' ? null : String,
    pets: [Pet],
}) { }    

const bill = new Person({
    joined: '2021-02-10',
    name: 'bill',
    age: '26',
    skills: ['python', 'dogwalking', 500],
    locale: 'vacation',
    pets: [
        {
            name: 'rufus',
            type: 'dog',
        },
    ]
});
```

That all compiles without error.  Let's use IntelliSense to examine the types of `bill`'s properties:

```
bill.age // (property) age?: number | undefined
bill.cast // (method) Model.cast(value: any, type?: any): any
bill.joined // (property) joined?: Date | undefined
bill.locale // (property) locale?: string | null | undefined
bill.name // (property) name?: string | undefined
bill.pets // (property) pets?: Pet[] | undefined
bill.publicAttributes /* (property) publicAttributes: {
    joined: DateConstructor;
    name: StringConstructor;
    age: NumberConstructor;
    skills: StringConstructor[];
    locale: (v: any) => StringConstructor | null;
    pets: (typeof Pet)[];
} & {} */
bill.skills // (property) skills?: string[] | undefined

console.log(bill.pets?.[0].type?.toUpperCase()) // "DOG"
```

Looks good!  The properties of `bill` are all the properties of `Model`, plus a strongly-typed `publicAttributes` type, plus all optional properties corresponding to `MFA<>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.9.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiaBvAsAKGn6A5sgC7QAOArgEYgCWwAgscQE61UXHIQAUAlBhz5h0FiQosAdhgC+Q-HOzy8wSMR4A3MCArIAXNDCSAngBpoxY2X2GT0ALzRJFECD4GjxwbhF5aAM2geS2sHe0cAETAuASwfX2ExYglpSWQAd2gork1tXT4AbmURGWhUCGRoAKCQyvDHADkKAFsqZBZY4oTRcSloJtb23J1kQq6FMpAKqsDgqzrw6ABlVlpJAk747p7kvq0RgDpieBW2df4ireFS8srqngQUEAPaCEfUOes+Te38YHhJBBSM0kKgHE4MhZ5sN8pdfngkiloCCnnCEjcpndZgwWCwwMYXhAcXjjJ9Rj94Yi9nlkAdmmAyDweLQuM0PCYBPYAHzeeEiKnSYgAC1eB1UQOZrPMtQA2gAGAC6Yyu6OV3Qx03utXggVqYUcAHJ-BRJMBiLQAQaKb8APQ2mbQY2m80A8xrDTwADWlSMiHIkBga3GvgFFhFEDFahhyGl0P2+T4wegim6ofjyDReEUxSB0XoVTeoJAw3Zxmt-N60h4SeE+wA-AcyCx4Mc9Wtc6bkDq4EXoAAfPs1-D1sUAoEsChm+AsBtNlst+ZVQHEIzALuBd4gJNqhQ4Yr-ZcTqcsHiIaJgcHoGTl4T+adBEAkaAy71maDphXQbsAeSoACtkDNA5kEkVZuFPc9vl5eFgnDQwYE8PgX2QYxP0cYVRXFdR03MWDXng2wy0bag6EYZg2A4LgIGQ1D+z7JwXDcTMSmKRRsyUbA9VgAAxBgAB4ABUeXsYoBLKAAPLhJEQGBtUCbJKjrLJokqPRRIkqSZKhaxu1ONYCGgJTx306A1K2MTkEkkCtLk-oWjaFhDIYwZHLM4QLKs6TZPmbsACF4HgR8jCcqgAqC6Q3PwDzNIQqhxzAM0IUyHgDlSsAWAICBS05Hk1n8dpoAAJSc4rIrwaLrJgFK0oyrLCJypd8sc4qlJ4-jCp5MroAqryv3-QDSCU9BnwAaSXaBX27ASFQMNrBJlEaFR5UouoEy4cC4otuObZomFWSjuEEjTKr6gCzWE4phsoGh6D2ijOG4AwxNKAAyHsnmgN6AAV0vNbQ+LmoSuXW7AnTNC1pE3bb4F28j2AeiAjssmLToGrlqy2aJiDqgT3CSoJ0syutsocHkoZ2u74aowTgb3UGTXBgF3tQaHYf2hGkc8rT4H686eCxnHy1DUAA2O3rN2g3wiFIa7SMpg7eFiHYkQF5NulYgjPAItJksJiBifq0nmZAVn5Y5oTLnYg8gXIEgzaoy9ikkMBmhsPT1lMYpagMd2CBwGRLj1L6SE3L7mzIGBHDm2zrGIe3uC5HAbQAKm0ypg+IUPw8jyWnBdmxjPWZjvegQuCEt6Bk5tOm1i4Fh-AS9OQ97ZGTp+lg-pAPiM6z+AI65cwJbiYRZduuGFYMHuizDvuIH9nBrZl9oIABeOc+H-A-3gNZkEQAwFM9rZnddn3Vg94owCIAwBgcw-hAgT1aFcOqZV9hU7-wEB4FUR8DE0EnuTvn1NAA0WhVAukkAaJyzhXCmWWGfAgH88CxxfjAkAABCbWkJ+BGynk8d+89OKLmDiwFekhe4R3BNHHygRrCkNXuPBGidsApzTtAEhZCKHr2KFvHee9lJcGYsfAuCDmKXxsM4FyzEH5PymAYMuMoFTMS-j-ERZwDL0TQcxFBk9m5PEURXKudMRZQHYU+Vu4stoU0YVRDGwgN6+GEafdRSCRAl19qxHASsrbgFMRwpmFitLkxhmvHgDjoC8LSPwg+Tt87OP0q48R197LtFcTI5+BhX4IIIVsFR2gbD-0NoAjQwDQEJTzJaaBjE4G+1cTo58GccnXgwMmOmC8xykCoLI8EOszH0MkGEnh28okGANAAJjlGMgAjAAWkmTMqZcoDSuKcSArprhlkXyviAsZAA2TZWx0lyOfAaMgxhhSWnMAaRA8ACDpG0I-dYyzoAAFY5SKlcXk3+ICwEVMgXUkgL8kzhO6Ksg0E5jQQAOXyEu1zbnQvRK4hU-tlQ4HWc8cR0A7RBDnHQywAhxEG0kQ5fs0ATQoH8HwtFsjIw22xTwV2FzEACE3LS7CNJSyxmsAbRCpZqWuAOJE3eWL7Q8Fxe0fFEThm7wNgpUl5LkCUqify54XzKj0vFR3Ms0A1UGzLqStB8rpKKqpdgdFBxhEipxeHCV2rhF6oQUailprzUoKtWKm1WqBAoINhnRRTqTXKrNTS0eZF2YO1YR6vutrvUkTHuGx6uchXRJUgAYQ6UeY4LAhFxPgeo9Nh5JxZrEdsm+7QC3jiLdOaRj8Ml5v0hW1gVaWAGOKGqv+GgAE8l9o2zN95NGMW0YCv+tkM5ISUf7T6shK7V2DQKo5MANWeslQuh16j-X0QVUq3exixyBVpF-AgPB0XKmtvug4h7j0hsBQ2eUCojjzAbMcAAqmQOhqbIDIH4AIbFAAiCI34ADiv66ZAA)

Comment: Woiw amazing description thanks! this will be so useful

Comment: sorry, to ask but im now implementing this and works great for base class, but im wondering if i can also somehow use the T as the return signature of the model method with option

so to have `toCamelPlainObject(): CasedFlatInterface` where `CaseFlatInterface` would be a flattened / morphed version of the schema? i guess one would be the flattening and second would be case changes, and how to affect methods of model?

Comment: I can't really say without a [mre], and the comments of an answer to an older question isn't a good place to explore that anyway.  Maybe you could post a new question and I might be able to provide assistance (or I might not, but then maybe *someone* can, as opposed to here where probably only I would see it)

Comment: o right just was finishing up what i meant (adding 2 example interfaces very tied to this question). if too much i can reopen new question [playground link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cejkqp?file=index.ts&view=editor)

Comment: This comment section is not really an appropriate place for followup questions.

Comment: thanks @jcalz. understood, posted dedicated follow up here if interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75301887/deriving-associated-interfaces-from-dynamic-typed-model